# Using Realloc in C

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, realloc

Its really a post for some advice in terms of the use of realloc, more specifically, if I could make use of it to simplify my existing code. Essentially, what the below does, it dynamically allocate some memory, if i goes over 256, then the array needs to be increased in size, so I malloc a temp array, with 2x the size, memcpy etc. ( see below ).

I was just wondering if realloc could be used in the below code, to simplify it, any advice, sample code, or even hints on how to implement it is much appreciated!

Cheers.

```
void reverse(char *s) {
char p;

switch(toupper(s[0])) 
{
    case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        p = s[strlen(s)-1];
        while( p >= s )
            putchar( p-- );
        putchar( '\n' );
        break;
    default:
        printf("%s", s);
        break;
}
printf("\n");
    }

    int main(void) {
char c;
int buffer_size = 256;
char *buffer, *temp;
int i=0;

buffer = (char*)malloc(buffer_size);
while (c=getchar(), c!=' ' && c!='\n' && c !='\t') 
{
    buffer[i++] = c;
    if ( i >= buffer_size )
    {
        temp = (char*)malloc(buffer_size*2);
        memcpy( temp, buffer, buffer_size );
        free( buffer );
        buffer_size *= 2;
        buffer = temp;
    }
}
buffer[i] = '\0';
reverse(buffer);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: A note of style: You should prefer **not** to cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: And `reverse` should take the argument as `const char *`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes** is the short answer. Here's how it would look:

```
if ( i >= buffer_size )
{
    temp = realloc(buffer, buffer_size*2);
    if (!temp)
        reportError();
    buffer_size *= 2;
    buffer = temp;
}
```

Note that you still need to use a temporary pointer to hold the result of `realloc()`; if the allocation fails you still have the original `buffer` pointer to the still-valid existing buffer.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the `buffer=temp`, does that not copy over the `temp` memory address? So if I free `temp` afterwards, I also free `buffer`? If true, when do I free the `temp` variable in order to not waste memory of having two identical strings allocated? Sorry I am trying to learn how this works.

Comment: buffer = temp does copy the address of temp to buffer. But it does not allocate another string...

Answer (score 1):

Realloc is pretty much exactly what you're looking for - you can replace that entire block inside the `if ( i >= buffer_size )` with something like:

```
buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, buffer_size*2);
buffer_size *= 2;
```

Notice that this ignores the error condition (if the return from `realloc` is `NULL`); catching this condition is left to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `realloc` could be used to slightly simplify your code.  If you're not interested in error-handling, then this:

```
char *tmp = malloc(size*2);
memcpy(temp, buffer, size);
free(buffer);
buffer = tmp;
```

is essentially equivalent to this:

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, size*2);
```

If you are interested in error-handling (and you probably should be), then you will need to check for `NULL` return values.  This is true of your original code too.

Comment: -1. if the realloc fails (by returning NULL), you've lost the reference to the original block.

Comment: @Graham: I explicitly said "if you're not interested in error-handling".  The OP doesn't have any error-handling in his original code, either.

Comment: This "error handling" isn't just some child's play like checking `std::cin >> n`; this one here may and will cause UB almost surely...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to simplify your code, you can replace

```
if ( i >= buffer_size )
{
    temp = (char*)malloc(buffer_size*2);
    memcpy( temp, buffer, buffer_size );
    free( buffer );
    buffer_size *= 2;
    buffer = temp;
}
```

with

```
if ( i >= buffer_size )
    buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size *= 2);
```

This does not take into account error checking, so you will need to check to make sure `realloc` doesn't return `NULL`.

Comment: `realloc` might return `NULL`, giving you an instant unrecoverable leak.

Comment: -1. if the realloc fails (by returning NULL), you've lost the reference to the original block.

Comment: @GrahamBorland I said you could replace his original code with that code. He didn't check for `NULL` there, so neither did I. But I added a note to mention it.